# GCP : PYTHONPATH screwed up when run program by "gcloud ml-engine local train"

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml-engine

This is my project structure :

```
└──myfolder
    └──myproject
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── tester.py
        ├── learners
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── bag_learner.py
        │   ├── dqn_learner.py
        │   ├── q_learner.py
        │   ├── q_learner.pyc
        │   ├── stock_dqn_learner.py
        │   ├── stock_q_base_learner.py
        │   └── stock_q_learner.py
        └── utility
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── analysis.py
            └── util.py
```

I usually run program by `python tester.py` at `myproject` directory.

Now I'm trying to run this program via `gcp` command. What I did was to move to `myfolder` directory and run program by `gcloud ml-engine local train --module-name=myproject.tester --package-path=myproject`. But it occured an error:

```
  File "myproject/learners/q_learner.py", line 6, in <module>
    from utility import *
ImportError: No module named utility
```

I thought that program couldn't recognize `myproject` directory as a `PYTHONPATH`. So I changed directory to `myproject`, and run program by `gcloud ml-engine local train --module-name=tester --package-path=./`. but it also occured an error:

```
/Users/Chois/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13/bin/python2: No module named tester
```

How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for your import to be something like:

```
import myproject.utility as utility
```

And then proceed along the path you were on which was to execute gcloud commands with myfolder as the working directory.